# Xcode debugger does not find my files

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, lldb, mach-o

I have taken over a rather large and complex project. A part of it is a static (C++) library, which is produced by an Xcode file (which actually was generated by CMake, I believe …)

The App itself is in a completely different project.

When I debug the app and want to step into the library, only assembly is shown. The symbols all seem to be there, prominently the output starts with `MyApp'Foo::bar(char const*) at Foo.cpp:102:`, and I see things like `0x1507a6:  bl     0x150838 ; Foo::fazbar(int) at Foo.cpp:206`

This, to me, says that symbolification is there and actually working.

Now, Foo.cpp is on my machine. I can open that file, and indeed, on line 206 Foo::fazbar is called.

The output from `nm` and `otool` does not look suspicious, either.

Why is lldb (Xcode's debugger) not finding my file? How can I tell lldb where the files are?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Using lldb's image lookup --address --verbose, I can see that the 
"Module: file" is correct, but the "CompileUnit:" is at a completely wrong address. I will investigate

Comment: Debug info exists in two places on Mac OS X: In object file (`.o` files) and in dSYM bundles (`.dSYM`).  When you compile & test a program, Xcode normally just leaves the debug info in the `.o` files. When it's time to finalize the binary, a `.dSYM` is typically created to put all the debug info in one place.  A static library (ranlib archive) is a collection of `.o` files. A binary that links against a `.a` lib will have all of the used debug info copied into its `.dSYM`. So - look for a `.dSYM`.  And try expanding the `.a` lib (`ar x libname.a` and looking in the `.o` files with `dwarfdump`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you moved source files around compared to when the library was built?

Comment: No, the code stayed right where it was. In fact, the binary of the library stayed right where it was, too and was linked from where it was built

Comment: The problem was that the wrong binary was linked! That contained paths to source on *someone else's* machine. Putting in the correct binary resolved the issue …